# Fullcalendar eventOverlap issue

Tags: ajax, events, fullcalendar, overlap

I use fullCalendar 2.6 and I only want one allday event per day.
I use this :

```
eventOverlap: false
```

It works if I put an event and move it on a day which has already an event : they won't overlap.
But if I click on a day which has already an event, it overlaps and I get 2 events (or more) at the same date... 
I use this too on my select function :

```
overlap: false
```

which does not do the trick..

What can I do ? any idea ?

And another issue is when I use ajax to send start/end dates, it only works when I click to add an event but not when I move it using arrows when I put my cursor on the edge of the event to change its size...

My code :

```
    function renderCalendar() {
        $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
            header: {
                left: 'prev,next today',
                center: 'title',
                right: 'month,basicWeek,basicDay',
            },
            defaultDate: dateNow,
            defaultView: 'month',
            lang: 'fr',
            height: 'auto',
            editable: true,
            allDaySlot: true,
            weekNumbers: false,
            timeFormat: 'H:mm',
            slotEventOverlap: false,
            weekends: true,
            selectable: true,
            selectHelper: true,
            eventOverlap: false,
            select: function(start, end) {
                var title = 'Occupé';
                var eventData;
                if (title) {
                    eventData = {
                        title: title,
                        start: start,
                        end: end,
                        allDay: true,
                        overlap: false,
                        color: '#bf0000',
                        textColor: '#ffffff',
                    };
                    $('#calendar').fullCalendar('renderEvent', eventData, true);
                }
                $('#calendar').fullCalendar('unselect');
                alert(start);
                alert(end);
            }
        });
```

Thanks for your help !

Answer (score 0):

well.. selectOverlap set to "false" is the solution :)
for the second problem, the solution must be eventResizeStop but I didn't find it yet

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
select: function(start, end) {
    var title = 'Occupé';
    var eventData;

    var sameDayEvents = $('#calendar').fullCalendar( 'clientEvents' ,function(event) {
        if (event.start.format('YYYY-mm-dd') == start.format('YYYY-mm-dd')) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    });

    if (!sameDayEvents.length && title) {
        eventData = {
            title: title,
            start: start,
            end: end,
            allDay: true,
            overlap: false,
            color: '#bf0000',
            textColor: '#ffffff',
        };
        $('#calendar').fullCalendar('renderEvent', eventData, true);
    }
    $('#calendar').fullCalendar('unselect');
    alert(start);
    alert(end);
}
```